# How to add UIToolbar to a NavigationController on Storyboard?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

I am not a huge fan of using Interface Builder and for that reason I am new to it.

I am trying to add a UIToolbar to a navigation controller but because Apple documentation is always very clear, I don't have a clue.

I am converting an old project to use Storyboards.

This is what I have done.

1. I have added a storyboard to the project
2. I have added a navigation controller to it
3. Because I want this navigation controller to show a toolbar at the bottom, I have clicked on the navigation controller and turned the toolbar on (see pic).

[image]

after that, a white rectangle appeared at the bottom of the navigation controller on interface builder. I think this is a the UIToolBar or a placeholder. I have tried to drag a BarButtonItem to this "space" and Xcode allowed, showing it like this:

[image]

When I run the app, the toolbar shows as a white rectangle at the bottom but not the button.

The button shows like this on the hierarchy:

[image]

I suppose the button should be inside the Toolbar item, but Xcode forbids dragging the item there.

How do I make the button show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your are trying to add an `UIToolBar` in a `UINavigationController` ...

Try in an `UIViewController` and that will work !

Edit:

[image]
[image]

Comment: did not work. What is the point of that white rectangle at the bottom if Xcode does not allow anything to be dragged there?

Comment: it was a problem on the storyboard. I recreated and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: If a tool bar is not appropriate for a navigation controller, then why does a navigation controller have "Show Toolbar" option?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

You just drag and drop the UINavigationItem on UINavigation RootViewController instead of UIToolbar.

It will allow you to put UIBarButtonItem on that UINavigationItem and works same like UIToolbar Button.

Comment: Can you answer with pictures of interface builder?

Comment: Hi RubberDuck, Here the image link [(http://i.imgur.com/HIDUjj7.png?1)] with specification.

Comment: This gives you a navigation bar, not a toolbar.